# what this command will do

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

Mistakenly i run this command

```
cat /etc/*
```

want to know what it can effect on my Linux system

what i was wanted to see the distribution of my sytem so

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

when i run this command it said that no such directory exist so tried the above command .
and stopped the above command in between , does the above command `cat /etc/*` can do any bad effect .

Comment: Handy tip: No harm as such, but sometimes if you cat a binary file your terminal will look all screwed up afterwards (until you close the window and reopen). You can fix that by (blindly) typing "reset".

Answer (score 4):

It just reads through every file in `/etc/` directory. Does not cause any harm, it's a read-only operation.

To see what `*` actually expands to, try

```
cd /etc
echo *
```

Comment: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat for more information about `cat`. tl;dr: cat echoes contents of files (or pipes), does not do anything to the files itself.

Answer (score 0):

CAT Command:  Allows you to look, modify or combine a file.

But as per your above command nothing to worry.

For to see the distribution info run

**$ cat /etc/issue**